# What is the most efficent way to create a tree in java?

Tags: java, tree

I am creating a tree in java to model the Extensive-form of a game for an AI. The tree will be an 25-ary tree (a tree in which each branch at most has 25 child branches) because at each turn of the game there are 25 different moves. Because the number of new branches that have to be created in each new layer of the tree is 25^n I'm very concerned with making this efficient. (I intend to remorselessly cut of branches to keep them from growing in order to keep things from getting bogged down). What is the best way to model such a tree when efficiency is such a concern? My first impression is to have a node object where each node has a parent node and an array of child nodes but this means creating a lot of objects. Ultimately these are my questions:

Is this the fastest way create and manage my tree?

What is a good way to figure out how much time any given algorithm or process in a program is going to take? (the only one I've thought of so far is to create a date before the process and then after and compare the # of milliseconds that have passed)

Any other thoughts are also welcome. My question implies and is related to a great number of other questions, i would expect. If i have been ambiguous or unclear please comment to let me know instead of down-voting and storming off as this isn't productive.

Comment: Perhaps you should first implement this using the straightforward approach (each node consists of an item and an array of child node references).  Then, analyze your access patterns.  You may find you don't even need a "tree" per-se.  Your problem may require nothing more than simple recursion.

Comment: I once heard someone say that pre-optimization is the root of all evil code.
Still, to measure time you can count in nanoseconds within java, that is going to be pretty accurate.
[nanoseconds](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: does java do nanoseconds? i thought the best it could do was milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, the way you described is the best approach. It'll perform reasonably well compared to anything else you could do and will be straightforward to implement.

Time and again people are asking questions about how to do something "efficiently". The best answer is nearly always, "don't even bother trying". Unless your improvement is an algorithmic one, it's unlikely to make much difference anyway, and especially in a case like this, the extra effort and complexity isn't worth whatever miniscule gain you might be able to achieve.

Putting it another way, and to borrow a quote (though I can't remember the originator), *the first rule of optimization is: don't.*

Having said that, if you really feel the need to squeeze every last drop of speed, you could try caching and re-using objects (instead of discarding them completely, keep track of them in a free object store, and then when you need to create a new object, first check the free object store to check if there is an existing one). As always, you'll need to measure performance before and after to see if it really helps (chances are it won't help much, unless physical memory is really constrained, in which case garbage collection can become expensive).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous comment about only optimizing once you have implemented the rest of the application.

On the other hand, I do realize a few things that may be of importance:

1. Branching factor of 25: Although not ridiculously huge, it is still large with respect to other problems. For a tree, you will definitely have to have a list for each node to indicate the list of SubNodes. You can do this either by making a Node class which has a collection of nodes within it, or have an external Map that maps a given node to a list of children nodes.
2. Removing and adding of elements will be done: This lends itself to a LinkedList implementation of the stored children since you don't want to perform costly removes and adds. A HashSet may work also, but the problem is that you may need more memory.
3. Iteration of the elements may or may not be done: If you want to iterate over the entire list at each step, LinkedLists are fine. If you want to prioritize the nodes then you may be saving memory by using a priority queue data structure. Priority queues are especially helpful if you are going to implement a heuristic function and evaluate which child to move to at any given node.

Thats all I have so far, but I'll keep updating if I think of more things, or if you update your content.